# How to update Debian Jessie to Debian Unstable/Testing

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I can't convert/updgrade my debian Jessie to Debian Unstable:

So, I edited /etc/apt/sources.list with vim.

```
deb http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

But, I obtain this error:

```
W: Can't Recovery http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/debian/dists/testing/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP : 2001:660:4208:100::24 80]

W: Can't Recovery http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/debian/dists/testing/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP : 2001:660:4208:100::24 80]

W: Can't recovery http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/debian/dists/testing/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP : 2001:660:4208:100::24 80]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heading says "
How to update Debian Jessie to Debian Unstable/Testing" but Unstable is one thing (Sid) and Testing is a different thing (Stretch)

I assume you want to upgrade to Testing (Stretch) and not Unstable (Sid)

You have produced a mixture of Jessie and Testing (Stretch).

Unless you are a computer expert and you need the source code you can stop all the lines which start deb-src - by putting a # at the beginning of those lines.

Change your sources list at: `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

And run:

```
apt-get update
```

Ready for first upgrade:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Follow this with:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the “/mirror” part in the URL.

Comment: @sorontar Sorry, but I really thought I was answering the OP’s question. He was complaining about an error message, and I explained what mistake caused that error message. What’s wrong with that? Anyway, I see the OP accepted the other answer, so I guess my answer wasn’t what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Given how short the wording was, that could have been said in a comment to the question. Answers should contain enough detail to understand how to apply them (adding a `mirror` word to the URL of the last two entries that are meant to add the testing branch of packages). This answer is missing such detail.